# Disable tooltip for disabled buttons

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jbutton

I am working on a swing gui which have many buttons. I have many actions in which buttons disable and enable at times. I want to set tooltips for only enabled buttons. When the button disables I don't want any tooltip for that button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try extending the Button class, and overloading getTooltip(). Something like:

```
public class MyButton extends JButton {
  public String getTooltip() {
     if (this.isEnabled()) {
       return super.getTooltip();
     }
     return null;
  }
}
```

Of course, this depends on Swing using getTooltip to get the info to draw the button; anyway I would try it.

Comment: Which result? Mind that there are no constructors defined, you should define the ones that you need.

Answer (score 2):

Add an extended `JButton` class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyButton extends JButton
{
  private String toolTip;

  @Override
  public void setToolTipText(String text)
  {
    super.setToolTipText(text);
    if (null != text) toolTip = text;
  }

  @Override
  public void setEnabled(boolean b)
  {
    super.setEnabled(b);
    super.setToolTipText(b ? toolTip : null);
  }
}
```

and use it instead.

Comment: I think Boris' answer is better. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setToolTipText-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove tooltip text.

You can also create your own class with overriden methods for enable/disable and doing it automatically.